# Issue with libproc (version _3_2_5 not defined in file libproc-3.2.8.so)

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, yum

There is an issue with libproc it seems. There is no mem usage or cpu usage info available. See:

```
[root@server ~]# free -m
free: relocation error: free: symbol kb_main_available, version _3_2_5 not defined in file libproc-3.2.8.so with link time reference

[root@server ~]# w
 03:06:02 up 112 days,  9:17,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    REMOVED           03:04    0.00s  0.00s   ?    -
```

I have tried reinstalling libproc using yum. However, the issue still remains. The system is running `CentOS release 6.7 (Final) 64Bit`.

Comment: How exactly did you install/reinstall `libproc`?  The behavior you report sounds similar to that described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817404/system-crash-after-oracle-installation-with-yum

Comment: @TJSaunders I reinstalled using `yum reinstall procps`. I did check out that question earlier however, I have not installed Oracle. This is also happening on 2 different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by installing an older version of procps (3.2.7) from Sourceforge http://procps.sourceforge.net/index.html

```
wget http://procps.sourceforge.net/procps-3.2.7.tar.gz #download
tar xfv procps-3.2.7.tar.gz #extract
cd procps-3.2.7/ #move to directory
make; make install #install


[root@server ~]# w
 03:28:40 up 115 days,  9:40,  1 user,  load average: 5.00, 5.05, 5.01
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0     03:23    0.00s  0.00s  0.00s w
```